# Cones of natural morphisms $i^!\rightarrow i^*$ and $f_!\rightarrow f_*$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathcal{D}^b(X)$ be the bounded derived category of constructible $\mathbb{C}$-sheaves on $X$.

(1) For any closed embedding $i:Z\rightarrow X$ and $A\in \mathcal{D}^b(X)$, there is a natural morphism $i^!(A)\rightarrow i^*(A)$ which induces a distinguished triangle in $\mathcal{D}^b(Z)$,$$i^!(A)\rightarrow i^*(A)\rightarrow B\xrightarrow{+1}.$$
(2) For any vector bundle $f:X\rightarrow Y$ and $A\in \mathcal{D}^b(X)$, there is a natural morphism $f_!(A)\rightarrow f_*(A)$ which induces a distinguished triangle in $\mathcal{D}^b(Y)$,$$f_!(A)\rightarrow f_*(A)\rightarrow C\xrightarrow{+1}.$$
Is it possible to describe the cones $B$ and $C$ explicitly? Even in the case that $A=\underline{\mathbb{C}}$ is the constant sheaf on $X$? Any comments will help! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For (2), every vector bundle can be compactified to a projective space bundle (the Proj of the graded ring of symmetric powers of the dual bundle plus a rank one trivial bundle). Let $j$ be the open immersion into the projective space bundle and $\pi$ the projection from the projective space bundle to $Y$.  Then $f= \pi \circ j$ so  $f_! A = \pi_! j_! A = \pi_* j_! A$ since $\pi$ is proper while $f_* A = \pi_* j_* A$ so $C$ is $\pi_*$ of the mapping cone of $j_! A \to j_* A$, which is just the restriction of $j_* A$ to the divisor at $\infty$.

Depending on $A$, this might be easy or difficult to compute.

However, for $A$ the constant sheaf, this is not the best way to describe the mapping cone. This is because, in this case, $f_* A$ is simply a constant sheaf and $f_!A $ is the constant sheaf shifted by twice the dimension $d$ of the vector bundle, so the mapping cone is simply an extension of two constant sheaves, associated to a cohomology class in $H^{2d}(Y,\mathbb Q)$.

The relevant cohomology class is the Euler class or top Chern class of the bundle $X$. The generator for the cohomology of $f_! \mathbb Q$ can be represented by a section of the bundle $X \to Y$, and the isomorphism between $f_* \mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Q$ can be calculated by pulling back to the zero section, so the cohomology class obtained by sending a generator on the map $f_* \mathbb Q \to f_* \mathbb Q$ is the pullback of a section to the zero section, i.e. the intersection of an arbitrary section with the zero section.

Answer (score 2):

Let $i$ be a closed immersion with complementary open immersion $j$. As in section 1.4.6 of Faisceaux Pervers, we have that the cone of $i^!\to i^*$ is $i^*j_*j^*$ and the cone of $j_!\to j_*$ is $i_*i^*j_*$.

If you have a general map $f:X\to Y$, you can usually factor $f$ as an open immersion and a proper map, then use the previous result to describe the cone of $f_!\to f_*$.

Comment: That’s not BBD that’s just the localization distinguished triangle ($i_*i^! \to id \to j_*j^*$ and it’s dual)

Comment: @crystalline There's a little work to be done to deduce what I said from the localization distinguished triangle and section 1.4.6 on Faisceaux Pervers explains this very well. (I also don't know any other reference that explains this precise statement.)

Comment: Sure but this is not a "result" of BBD and they surely were not the first to think of applying $i^*$ to this distinguished triangle. It is misleading to attribute a straightforward exercise to 3 of the greatest minds to think about sheaf theory. To be clear I wouldn't take issue if you had said "see BBD 1.4.6 for a reference which explains this very well", but as is it gives a wrong impression that this is some kind of deep result.

Comment: Sorry if I gave this impression. This is surely not a deep result and not at all comparable with the deep stuff that is in BBD.

Comment: I believe that Gabber is also an author of "Faisceaux Pervers."